# Why is removal of sprintf() from the following code causing segmentation fault?How to deal with it?

Tags: c, linux, printf

I intend to remove `sprintf()` from my code because its not needed any more in my code .But when I do that,it is causes a  segmentation fault,whereas it works fine when `sprintf()` is there.Please tell me the reason for this and how to resolve this problem.

```
unsigned char status_str[40]={0};
sprintf(status_str,"found HTTP:%dth time\n",(count+1));
```

Comment: Removing `sprintf` from your current example certainly won't cause a crash - you'll just be left with a variable declaration.  Can you provide a full example that works and where removing `sprintf` causes a crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using [sprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) is deprecated (or at least not recommended, see the *BUGS* section of the linked man page), it is a dangerous function (because of possible buffer overflow). You should use `snprintf` (which is standard since C99, i.e. since previous century) and code instead

```
snprintf (status_str, sizeof(status_str), 
          "found HTTP:%dth time\n", (count+1));
```

<sup>The reason why `snprintf` is preferable to `sprintf` is that even if the output overflows the buffer, `snprintf` won't overflow the given size, while `sprintf`, not knowing any size limit, will overflow.</sup>

Then, if your `sprintf` avoids some segmentation fault (assuming it does not overflow `status_str`), you've been hurt by some [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ***elsewhere*** in your program.

I would imagine that doing the `sprintf` fills perhaps [the stack location of] some uninitialized value with some stuff which happens to make it work later.

I suggest compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -g` (improving the code till you get no warning) and use the `gdb` debugger (its `watch` command is helpful). You could also use `valgrind` to hunt memory leaks (and *some* uninitialized access).

If you want some more help please show some more source code.

With a GNU libc, you could also use [asprintf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Output.html) which allocates and fills some heap-`malloc`-ated zone. This function is GNU specific (and you should ensure the pointer is `free`-d later).

Comment: Mr.Basile, can you elaborate little more on that?That means `sprintf()` is not standard C anymore?

Comment: I had the notion the following is a good site for reference  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/   Tell me what to do now?What else is deprecated?...Sigh.....So it's improper to use `sprintf()`?

Comment: `sprintf` is standard, but so is `snprintf` and recent documentations mark `sprintf` as being buggy (read the *BUG* section of man page) and I believe that `sprintf` is obsolete in the next Posix standard.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly does it segfault? If you really just remove it and the code doesn't reference status_str anymore then it could indicate a stack corruption. The error might occur somewhere earlier and it works randomly, but when the stack layout changes, an seemingly unrelated part of the code can break for no obvious reason.

For example: If an earlier code overwrites the stack with some values, and these values are reaching into status_str, no harm is done, but when that is gone, something else is overwritten and this can cause the segfault.

That's just a guess though. So you should check the code that is called before that particular function is called.

To clarify: It can be any memory, not neccessarily the stack, depends on where this is defined.